# fluent Nhibernate unknown path

Tags: nhibernate, fluent, sharp-architecture

I have a project with sharp architecture on VS2010 and I'm getting 
Server Error in '/' Application.

---

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

the weird thing is on the STACK TRACE It references to a path "e:\WorkSpaces\Git\SharpArchitecture..." that I have not in my server
Can anybody tell me what is this and it there is a resolution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace contains file paths where assemblies were built. I suppose the exception is from the custom library S#arp architecture, which you did not build yourself.